# How to store the page number in ReactJS (not in state) to construct the GET URL with page number from 1 to 5

Tags: reactjs

I found it is difficult to store the page number in the variable of this.state to construct GET URL with different page numbers (from 1 to 5). Because if you store it in state, when you want to add 1 to this number and get the data from next page, this.setState may not work, which can lead to the repetition of GET data from API.

if I store it in a global variable, when I back to this page, the number won't change back to the initial value.

Comment: post code snippet or fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

The setState works. but because it's asynchronous you need to use the correct overload.

from React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous):

```js
// Wrong
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment,
});

// Correct
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  counter: prevState.counter + props.increment
}));
```

If you want to execute some code after the state is updated you can add a second argument like so:

```
this.setState((prevState) => 
  counter: prevState.counter + 1,
  (newState) => console.log(newState.counter) //do something with the updated state
);
```